# Hyper-V Server Backup

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2

We are running a test install of Hyper-V Server 2008 (Stand Alone Free Version).

I was wondering if there is anyway to backup the VHD's using the command line as this is all you have.  I know you can use System Center Data Protection Manager but this costs a fortune.  We don't mind if they pause the VM's for a few minutes. :)

Any help would be great.
Thanks 
Al

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but what happens if you just try to do a regular copy (ie. xcopy) of the VHD without pausing the server? Does it result in an inconsistent or unbootable image?

Comment: Here is the solution I had come up with. http://serverfault.com/questions/55789/command-line-backup-of-running-hyper-v-images-using-volume-shadow-copies-vss-an

Answer (score 2):

If you have Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 you can enable PowerShell ([Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210125074622/http://geekswithblogs.net/twickers/archive/2009/11/04/136013.aspx)) and then use the PowerShell Management Library for Hyper-V available on codeplex.

The PowerShell library will allow you to script the pausing/shutdown of virtual machines before backing up the VHD files and restarting them automatically.  There are several commands in the library listed under, Backing up, exporting and snapshotting VMs.